# Strong and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3),\  x \in L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3) , \  \| x_n \|_{L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3)} = C \ (const.) \ , \ \|x\|_{L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3)} > 0,$

and$\  x_n \to x \ weakly \ in \ L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3) $ .

Does $x_n , x$ exist such that $\|x\|_{L^2 (\mathbb{R} ^3)} < C \ $?

Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: Why does the title mention "strong convergence"?

Comment: $\| x \| = C \iff x_n \to x \ strongly$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then this is possible in any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Let $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a orthonormal system and set $x_i = e_1 + e_{i+1}$. Then, $\|x_i\| = \sqrt{2}$, $x_i \rightharpoonup e_1$ and $\|e_1\| = 1 < \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: That's right! (In the case of infinite dimention)    Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, of course - in finite dimensions you do not need the notion of weak convergence.